# How do i detect collision between my created objects and the screen border?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'd like to detect a collision between the cards that I have created and the screen border.

For example, when the cards fly out of the user's view, they should automatically bounce back in when touching the edge of the screen.

How do I identify a collision between the edge of the screen and the cards object?

At the moment, this generates cards that float across the screen & spin. But when they reach the border they disappear.

I know how to adjust the speed so that it travels in a negative direction, but am looking to understand how to detect this collision.

Here's my code.

```
const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, screenWidth / screenHeight, 0.1, 1000 );
const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
const renderCard = async (card) => {
    const cardFile = `./src/assets/img/${card.asset}`

    const geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(1, 1.5, 0);
    const texture = await new Promise((resolve) => {
        const loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
        loader.load(cardFile, (texture) => {
            resolve(texture);
        });
    });

    const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
        map: texture
    });

    return new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
};

async function prepareScene() {
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
    camera.position.z = 5;
}

function getCardPosition(card, position = 'x') {
    if (!card.model.speed) {
        card.model.speed = {};
        card.model.speed['x'] = 0.05;
        card.model.speed['y'] = 0.05;
    }

    return card.model['position'][position] + (card.model.speed[position]);
}

async function animate() {
    cards = await Promise.all(cards.map(async card => {
            if (!card.speed) {
                card.speed = {
                    x: 0.01,
                    y: 0.01
                }
            }

            if (!card.model) {
                const box = new THREE.Box3();
                card.model = await renderCard(card);
                card.model.geometry.computeBoundingBox();
                card.box = box;
                scene.add(card.model);
            }

            card.model.position.x = getCardPosition(card, 'x');
            card.model.position.y = getCardPosition(card, 'y');

            card.box.copy(card.model.geometry.boundingBox).applyMatrix4(card.model.matrixWorld);

            card.model.rotation.x += 0.01;
            card.model.rotation.y += 0.01;

            return card;
        }
    ));

    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
}

window.onload = async () => {
    await prepareScene();
    await animate();
};
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two things we need to know to prevent an object from going off the edge of the screen:

1. the screen boundaries
2. the boundaries of the object we want to contain within the screen

**Screen Boundaries**

Top left of screen:

`screen.x = 0, screen.y = 0`

The right edge of the screen:

`screen.width = window.innerWidth` // for example

The bottom edge:

`screen.height = window.innerHeight`

**Object Boundaries:**

the actual position of the top left corner of the object:

`obj.x = 0, obj.y = 0` // values change every animation frame

the height and width of the object

`obj.width = 100, obj.height = 150`

Armed with this info, for every animation frame we can check to see if the object's boundaries cross the edge of the screen. Below is assuming a non-spinning rectangular object.

```
// check left side
if (obj.x < screen.x)
     {obj.x = screen.x} // pull the object back onto the screen

// check right side
if (obj.x + obj.width > screen.width)
     {obj.x = screen.width - obj.width} // pull the object back onto the screen

// check top edge
if (obj.y < screen.y)
     {obj.y = screen.y} // pull the object back onto the screen

// check bottom edge
if (obj.y + obj.height > screen.height)
     {obj.y = screen.height - obj.height} // pull the object back onto the screen
```

This is the basic method of containing an object within the screen boundaries.
When the rectangular object is spinning there is a little added complexity and it may be easier to assume the object is circular, then we would just need to check for when the `center of the object + the object's radius` crosses the screen boundaries. Using the circular object approach would mean that part of the object would cross the screen boundaries, if the circle is wholly contained within the rectangular object, i.e. `circle.radius = rectangle.width`, but you may find that it gives acceptable results.